# UWP Button press on External USB Camera

Tags: c#, camera, uwp, usb

I have a UWP application that needs to access an External USB Camera with ability to know when a button press occurred on the camera.  I am able to use MediaCapture to locate the camera and display a video stream.  The issue is that I have no way of determining if the button was pressed on the device. I tried connecting to it using **Windows.Devices.Usb**, but was not successful since the device class is **0e**, which is not in the list of supported class codes (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/dn312121(v=vs.85).aspx#step3). When I make a call to `UsbDevice.FromIdAsync(mydeviceId)`, I always get Null returned. At this point I am trying to determine what my options are to determine the button press.

I do have the following in my package manifest:

```
<DeviceCapability Name="usb">
     <Device Id="vidpid:19ab 1050">
        <Function Type="classId:0e * *" />
     </Device>
</DeviceCapability>
```

Comment: If you want to detect the button on the External USB Camera? If so, you should be able to check the OEM of the camera device that is it support pass the button signal to the pc. Also it seems most External USB Camera that have not Button on it. So why do you want to detect it?

Comment: This is for a microscope USB camera that has a button to allow a user ability to capture an image without interaction with the PC. The issue is that the device class id is 0e.  Also doesn't seem like an Image device class is supported by Windows.Devices.Usb namespace

Comment: I have exactly the same problem. But for not simplifying things, I am in Java. Have you find a way ? Is it by chance this microscope USB as well: https://plugable.com/products/usb2-micro-250x ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did resolve my issue.  The problem was with my Capability definition.  I had Page and Usage values reversed. Below is the updated Capability that worked.

```
<DeviceCapability Name="humaninterfacedevice">
      <Device Id="vidpid:19ab 1000">
        <Function Type="usage:FFA0 0001" />
      </Device>
      <Device Id="vidpid:19ab 1020">
        <Function Type="usage:FFA0 0001" />
      </Device>
</DeviceCapability>
```

Comment: This is an interesting reply. I have been able to get devices working using Hid as well, but I'm struggling to get devices working using Name="usb". Have you given up on this?